# Can it be quickly? Or it should be quick

Tags: sentence-construction, adjectives, adverbs, sentence-structure

I'm just a little bit confused about the [following](https://books.google.ro/books?id=MYAJhoSJd_MC&pg=PA9&dq="let+it+be+quickly"&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwieq5qB-ffKAhXnDpoKHU9BAa4Q6AEIMzAE#v=onepage&q=%22let%20it%20be%20quickly%22&f=false) example:

> 1. If we must kill them, let it be quickly and cleanly, without excuses.

compared to the [following](https://books.google.ro/books?id=sbLuAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT152&dq="let+it+be+quick"&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjehp2flvjKAhXBFg8KHcacDmsQ6wEILTAD#v=onepage&q=%22let%20it%20be%20quick%22&f=false) one:

> 2. Let it be quick, she prayed. For God's sake let it be quick...

I have done my homework reading [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/127379/can-the-verb-be-be-modified) and [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/127057/what-does-mostly-modify/127064?noredirect=1#comment262429_127064) and [here](https://www.englishforums.com/English/LinkingVerbsAndAdverbs/nnncc/post.htm), but I have to admit that I am still unsure whether **quickly** in #1and **quick** in #2 are adjectives or adverbs. After all, what do they exactly modify?

Certainly, generally speaking, quick can be used as an adverb or as an adjective but quickly can only be an adverb.

Comment: *quick* is an adjective. (It can also be an adverb to mean *soon.)* Add *-ly* to make it the adverb *quickly.* (This means rapidly.) The adverb stays with the verb, the adjective stays with the noun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an interesting questiion.  What exactly *do* they modify?  The answer is, of course, if they modify a noun, you need to use the adjective, and if a verb, then the adverb.  Now, the first sentence, while common, isn't really correct.  [Edit: Fumblefingers' comment makes me think twice about that.  Anyway...] Look at these:

> If we must kill them, let us do so quickly and cleanly, without excuses.
>   If we must kill them, let the killing be quick and clean, without excuses.

In your first sentence, these two constructions are getting crossed: *it* actually refers to the killing.  However, *it* is also more concise than *us do so*. There are times when informal conversation performs this sort of abbreviation at the expense of absolutely correct grammar.  In this case, of course, the most concise version is:

> If we must kill them, let it be quick and clean, without excuses.

Clearly, the *it* refers to the killing.  Perhaps the reason that the sentence sticks with the adverb is because the noun *killing* hasn't been mentioned, so there's a bit of an added thought process to mentally fill it in.

This tendency to abbreviate is probably why you will often see this substitution of an adjective for an adverb, especially in AmE:

> If we must kill them, let us kill them quick and clean.

You pretty much have to learn on a case-by-case basis when colloquial English will allow this sort of transgression and when it will not.

Comment: For OP's first example I find it more natural to assume a deleted *let it be [**done**] quickly* to be adverbially modified. But of course *quick* can be adverbial as well as adjectival - *Come quick!* and *Come quickly!* are synonymous.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Now that you mention it, so do I.  :)

Answer (score 2):

Your first quote

> If we must kill them, let it be quickly and cleanly, without excuses.

should possibly read

> If we must kill them, let it be **done** quickly and cleanly, without excuses.

and seems to be an allusion to

> *(Macbeth Act 1 Scene 7)*
>   If it were done when ’tis done, then ’twere well
>   It were **done** quickly

In your second example, **quick** is the subject complement for **it**

Both uses as **adverb** and **adjective** are correct.

Comment: I was quite certain that some people would introduce a **done** to say that quickly modifies it,  @FumbleFingers, and I feel it right.

Comment: It is one of the most famous soliloquies

Comment: @LucianSava I confess I didn't think of it.  It seems entirely right to me as well.