# What is the difference between quick and quickly when both of them are meant as adverbs?

Tags: adverbs

[image: Page of document listing adverbs]

This page is taken out of quite a respectable book.  It's 'Grammar and vocabulary for First Certificate'.

The table demonstrates that there are two adverbs *quick* and *quickly*, but it provides no comments or explanation of the difference in their usage.

Can you, please, help me to figure out this difference.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can it be quickly? Or it should be quick](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/81428/can-it-be-quickly-or-it-should-be-quick)

Comment: @FumbleFingers You know, I've been looking at that proposed duplicate for a week now, and I'm coming to the conclusion it doesn't address the present question. It really sticks to adjectival vs adverbial uses, but not "*quick* as adverb". I think the OP's question boils down to "The book seems to be implying that both 'Bill ran quick' and 'Bill ran quickly' are valid, so when would I use which one?"

Answer (score 2):

Quick is actually an adjective but is often used as an adverb ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/fast-quick-or-quickly)), and Quickly is an adverb.

Here is a [link](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/94716) to another page that seems to answer your question:

> I see quickly as the correct adverb; I would correct my children if
> they said:
>
> > He's running quick.
>
> However quick is widely used as an adverb, and in some phrases seems
> to work better:
>
> > a get rich quick scheme
>
> [This article has some interesting observations](https://blog.oup.com/2007/08/adverb/)

Comment: @dilek22 Note, the main focus of the page you posted is about *comparison* forms of adjectives. It might not want to imply that all of them could be used in the "Bill runs ___" type of sentence. Some are widely accepted that way—Bill works hard, Bill arrives early, Bill leaves late—but some might be frowned on (but used anyway colloquially): Bill sings loud, Bill drives slow. Maybe the key difference is that these have "-ly" forms and hard, early, late, etc don't (or such words like "lately" have different meanings). The tendency is: If there's an applicable "-ly" form, use it.

Comment: @AndyBonner I see what you mean now. Thank you about stating what the tendency is cause i really get puzzled every time I come across 'drive slowlier'-like phrases.

Comment: @dilek22 I should also emphasize, this is one of those cases in which the "mistake" is widely, widely used in everyday informal speech, to the point that insisting on the "correct" version could be seen as unreasonable. "Run quick," "drive slow," "talk loud" are very, very common. (However, as the book points out, "quicklier" is not.)

Comment: @AndyBonner thank you so much! your help and comments are invaluable!